# Is there a .thenCompose() for CompletableFuture that also executes exceptionally?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I want to execute a `CompletableFuture` once another `CompletableFuture` finishes, regardless of whether or not the first one completes exceptionally (`.thenCompose()` only runs when execution completes normally).

For example:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 1L)
    .whenComplete((v, e) -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("HERE");
        } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
            return;
        }
    }))
    .whenComplete((v, e) -> System.out.println("ALL DONE"));
```

This prints

```
ALL DONE
HERE
```

and I would like it to be

```
HERE
ALL DONE
```

preferably without nesting the second `whenComplete()` inside the first.

Note that I don't care about the returned result/exception here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to use `.handle((r, e) -> r)` to suppress the error:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { throw new RuntimeException(); })
    //Suppress error
    .handle((r, e) -> r)
    .thenCompose((r) -> 
         CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("HELLO")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use whenCompleteAsync instead of CompletableFuture.runAsync:

```
    CompletableFuture<Long> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 1L)
    .whenCompleteAsync((v, e) -> { 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("HERE");
        } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
            //nothing
        }
        //check that thowing an exception also executes the next cf
        throw new RuntimeException("exception");
    })
    .whenCompleteAsync((v, e) -> System.out.println("ALL DONE (exception thrown: " + e + ")"));

    System.out.println("CF code finished");
    System.out.println(cf.get());
```