# How to get combined effects of whenComplete and thenCompose?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to come up with a CompletableFuture with the combined effects of `whenComplete` and `thenCompose`, specifically:

1. Returns a `CompletionStage` instead of just a result, similar to `thenCompose`.
2. Executes even when previous stage completes exceptionally, similar to `whenComplete`, and does not stop the exception from propagating.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576569/is-there-a-thencompose-for-completablefuture-that-also-executes-exceptionally) is close to what I'm trying to achieve but I don't want to use `handle` which hides the exception. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Undeleted my answer. I believe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: What’s the point of returning a `CompletionStage` in the exceptional case, when the stage will be ignored?

Comment: I'd say, just use .handle((val, err) -> ...), and in the lamba rethrow a new CompletionException(err) when necessary. That should do the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe `CompletionStage` or `CompletableFuture` provides any single method for this. However, combining `handle` with `thenCompose` should do what you want, if I understand your requirements correctly.

A `handle` stage is executed whether the parent stage has completed normally or exceptionally and gives you access to the result or error, respectively. From this stage you could return another `CompletionStage` which would either be completed normally or exceptionally depending on what arguments the `handle` stage receives.

```
handle((T result, Throwable error) -> {
    if (error != null) {
        return CompletableFuture.<T>failedStage(error);
    } else {
        return processResult(result); // returns CompletionStage<T>
    }
});
```

Now you have a `CompletionStage<CompletionStage<T>>`. Now we execute a flat map operation by invoking `thenCompose`:

```
thenCompose(Function.identity());
```

Which gives us a `CompletionStage<T>`. This `CompletionStage<T>` will be whatever instance was returned by `handle`. If that instance was a failed stage then the exception is still propagated; otherwise, the result is passed to whatever stage is dependent on the `thenCompose` stage and processing continues normally.

You can see this with the following example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methodThatReturnsCompletionStage()
                .handle((result, error) -> {
                    if (error != null) {
                        return CompletableFuture.<String>failedStage(error);
                    } else {
                        return processResult(result);
                    }
                })
                .thenCompose(future -> {
                    System.out.println("#thenCompose invoked");
                    return future; // Identity function
                })
                .thenApply(result -> {
                    System.out.println("#thenApply invoked");
                    return result; // Identity function (exists to show intermediary stage)
                })
                .whenComplete((result, error) -> {
                    System.out.println("#whenComplete invoked");
                    if (error != null) {
                        error.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(result);
                    };
                });
    }

    private static CompletionStage<String> methodThatReturnsCompletionStage() {
        return CompletableFuture.completedStage("Hello");
        // return CompletableFuture.failedStage(new RuntimeException("OOPS"));
    }

    private static CompletionStage<String> processResult(String result) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result + ", World!");
    }

}
```

This will result in each stage being invoked and an output of `Hello, World!`. But if you switch `methodThatReturnsCompletionStage()` to return the failed stage instead then `thenApply` is skipped (because the future has failed) and the exception is given to `whenComplete` (which, like `handle`, is invoked for both normal or exceptional completion).

***Note:** Everything above uses the `CompletionStage` interface directly but using `CompletableFuture` works just as well (and may be preferable).*